# Bootstrap sass variable for bg-light

Tags: colors, sass, bootstrap-4

I am building a page where elements take bootstrap's default values, i.e.

```
#some-element {
    background-colour: $code-colour;
    font-size: $font-size-base;
    ...
    colour: $bg-light ??
}
```

I am looking for the variable that controls the colour of `.bg-light` class, but can't seem to locate it in `_variables.scss`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SASS variable is simply called: `$light` as explained here: 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/theming/#theme-colors

Also, there are no CSS properties named `colour` or `background-colour`. Use `color`...

```
#some-element {
    background-color: $code-colour;
    font-size: $font-size-base;
    color: $light;
}
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/go/7oDktA3xCt